# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'serviceObj.reduce')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a problem when using `useState` with reducer.

I know that `useState` have limitations such as its not update immediately and in my case its the problem.

I'm pulling data from Firestore and using `useState` to hold it for further use, but at first time i click on button for example I get the following error:

[image: error]

After the second click all data is presenting perfectly.

Is there any way to prevent this error from appearing?

Firestore Query:

```
const handleService = (bUID) => {
      const serviceListTmp = [];
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).collection("my-appointments").where("businessId", "==", bUID).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          serviceListTmp.push(doc.data());
        })
        console.log("Service List TMP =>", serviceListTmp);
        setServiceObj(serviceListTmp);
        //console.log("Service Obj ", serviceObj);
      })
    }
```

Error lies here:

```
const data = serviceObj.reduce(reducer, []);
```

Comment: How do you define your state for `serviceObj`? Just a random guess but probably initially you forgot to set `[]` to that as a value and that's why your `reduce()` fails because it only can run on arrays. If that's the case, the solution could be `const [serviceObj, setServiceObj] = useState([])`.

Comment: const [serviceObj, setServiceObj] = useState();

Comment: I Will slap myself if this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are running `.reduce()` not on an array in your code. Probably you forgot to set initially your state the value `[]`.

Based on the comment section's clarification you need to define your state as:

```
const [serviceObj, setServiceObj] = useState([])
```

Other than this, your code looks just fine.

Comment: That's seems to work, i will run a serious check with a lot of data and i will comment here if there is any change

Comment: @OsherRevach Awesome, happy to help!